# Texture Coordinate Picking

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to detect where in a texture on an object a user has clicked so that I may redraw the texture in response.

I know that I can render my objects with a color-coded texture to a separate render target and use gl.readPixels to see which coded pixel was clicked, then calculate back to what my X and Y coordinates should be in the texture.

I seem to be able to do this reliably for the Y axis, but not the X axis.

This is my (extraneous bits of code removed) Three.js setup:

```
var canvas = document.getElementByID("output"),
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas: canvas,
    alpha: true,
    antialias: true
}),
back = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(canvas.width, canvas.height),
scene = new THREE.Scene(),
pickingScene = new THREE.Scene(),
pickingPixelBuffer = new Uint8Array(4),
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, canvas.width / canvas.height, 0.1, 1000),
textureWidth = 1024,
textureHeight = 1024,
texture = generateTexture(textureWidth, textureHeight),
pickingTexture = generatePickingTexture(textureWidth, textureHeight), 
obj = textured(shell(w, 5, 10), texture),
objPicker = textured(shell(w, 5, 10), pickingTexture);

back.generateMipmaps = false;

scene.add(camera);
scene.add(obj);
pickingScene.add(objPicker);
```

So for an object like this:
[image]

The picking texture ends up looking like this:
[image: the picking texture]

The `generateTexture` function isn't really that important. The `textured` function is just a short-hand for applying a texture to a geometry object:

```
function textured(geometry, txt){
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0xffffff,
        map: txt,
        transparent: false,
        shading: THREE.FlatShading,
        side: THREE.DoubleSide
    });

    var obj = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    return obj;        
}
```

And the `generatePickingTexture` function is thus:

```
function generatePickingTexture(w, h){
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = w;
    canvas.height = h;
    var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
    var gfx = texture.image.getContext("2d"),
            l = w * h,
            pixels = gfx.createImageData(w, h);
    for(var i = 0, p = 0; 
            i < l; 
            ++i, p += 4){
        pixels.data[p]   = (0xff0000 & i) >> 16;
        pixels.data[p+1] = (0x00ff00 & i) >> 8;
        pixels.data[p+2] = 0x0000ff & i;
        pixels.data[p+3] = 0xff;
    }
    gfx.putImageData(pixels, 0, 0);

    texture.needsUpdate = true;
    return texture;
}
```

Then I try to perform the picking:

```
function pick(){
    renderer.render(pickingScene, camera, back, true);

    var gl = renderer.getContext();
    gl.readPixels(pointerX, canvas.height - pointerY, 1, 1, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pickingPixelBuffer);
    var i = (pickingPixelBuffer[0] << 16) | 
            (pickingPixelBuffer[1] << 8) | 
            pickingPixelBuffer[2],
            // x = i % textureWidth,
            x = (i - Math.floor(textureWidth / 512) * 256) % textureWidth, // EDIT2: this is the hack
            y = i / textureWidth;
    console.log(x, y);
}
```

As I said, the y coordinate works out perfectly. But the x coordinate is way off. As I drag the mouse down the screen, the x coord warps to the right, jumping about 1/4th of the width of the texture. As I drag the mouse across the screen, if I can avoid any vertical mouse movement, the x coord moves at the right offset, but is not at the right location. It seems to jump location every time I hit one of the 1/4 marks.

Since it *is* 1/4th, it seems likely that my math for generating the texture is wrong. But for the life of me, I can't see it.

EDIT: indeed, if I restrict my texture to be only 256 pixels wide, it works perfectly.

<strike>EDIT2: I've figured out a hack to the `pick` function that fixes the problem, but I don't understand why it works.</strike>

EDIT3: Well, "working" under the proviso that the object is at a 1-to-1 display ratio for the screen. There are still some problems with different orientations, but that is unrelated to this other issue. I suspect it's something to do with resampling of the texture.

EDIT4: it was the default texture filtering settings.

Answer (score 1):

OH! It was all the texture filtering, this entire time. I needed to change my `generatePickingTexture` function to:

```
function generatePickingTexture(w, h){
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = w;
    canvas.height = h;
    var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas, THREE.UVMapping, THREE.RepeatWrapping, THREE.RepeatWrapping, THREE.NearestFilter, THREE.NearestFilter);
    var gfx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
            l = w * h,
            pixels = gfx.createImageData(w, h);
    for(var i = 0, p = 0; i < l; ++i, p += 4){
        pixels.data[p]   = (0xff0000 & i) >> 16;
        pixels.data[p+1] = (0x00ff00 & i) >> 8;
        pixels.data[p+2] = (0x0000ff & i) >> 0;
        pixels.data[p+3] = 0xff;
    }
    gfx.putImageData(pixels, 0, 0);

    texture.needsUpdate = true;
    return texture;
}
```